# Где утекает память?

Tags: c

Подскажите, где я не освобождаю память и с каждой итерацией цикла она утекает?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char *str_cpy(const char *str0, const char *str1) {
    char *str;
    if ((str = malloc(strlen(str0) + strlen(str1) + 1)) != NULL) {
        str[0] = '\0';
        strcat(str, str0);
        strcat(str, str1);
    }
    return str;
}

bool fs_isdir(const char *path) {
    struct stat sb;
    if (stat(path, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool net_exists_interface(const char* interface) {
    DIR *dir = opendir("/sys/class/net");
    if (dir != NULL) {
        struct dirent *ent;
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            char *path = str_cpy("/sys/class/net/", ent->d_name);
            if (strcmp(ent->d_name, interface) == 0 && fs_isdir(path)) {
                free(path);
                return true;
            }
            free(path);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void net_stat_interface(const char *interface) {
    puts(interface);
}

void net_stat(char *interfaces[]) {
    for (int i = 0; interfaces[i] != NULL; i++) {
        if (net_exists_interface(interfaces[i]))
            net_stat_interface(interfaces[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char *interfaces[] = {"eth0", "lo", "ccmni0", "tralala"};
    while (true) {
        net_stat(interfaces);
        sleep(1);
        //cpu_stat();
        //mem_stat();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну то, что malloc-ом выделили - освобождается, а вот есть еще `opendir/readdir` - здесь вы наверно потеряете. Внизу обязательно `closedir(dir)`

Comment: @АлексейСаровский после readdir() вызывать free() не нужно - смотрите документацию http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir

Comment: @gbg `closedir` - то надо? Да, согласен, readdir зря указал

Comment: @АлексейСаровский надо, я как раз про это ответ настрочил ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После `opendir` стоит делать `closedir` как минимум